# Can cosmic rays be considered as a "galactic resource" in a hypothetical planetary colonization science fiction world?

Tags: science-fiction, space-colonization, solar-system, radiation

Like a star's energy, planetary biomass, etc are precious resources for any spacefaring civilization.
Can cosmic rays (for producing energy, causing beneficial but erratic effects like hulk's body mass increase etc) be considered as a precious resource as well?

Comment: I love the idea of Hulkification as a natural resource.  Talk about a Green New Deal!

Comment: Didn't the hulk become the hulk from gamma radiation from an atomic bomb? That's why he's green like uranium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not the Cosmic Rays but the sites.**

Ordinary cosmic rays are just fast moving particles in space. They come from stars and are as common as sunlight. They are too common to be considered precious and not worth fighting over. You can just get them from your sun rather than your enemies' sun.

**Exotic Cosmic Rays**

[image]

What might be worth fighting over are the high-energy rays produced by exotic stellar phenomena. For example a pulsar or two white dwarfs orbiting each other. These will produce different types tasty rays. Perhaps they can be used for something special. Something you want your enemy to not do.

Remember these guys are still humongous. There are still enough cosmic rays to go around. But you might want to capture these sites to prevent your enemy using the rays.

Comment: gorgeous pictures!

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, the Hulk isn't the one associated with Cosmic Rays, that's the Fantastic Four.

But no, I don't think they can be considered a valuable resource.

Space is very very big, and cosmic rays, though significantly rarer than ordinary starlight, are pretty much everywhere.

There's very little Space Nation A can do to prevent Space Nation B from receiving whatever amount of cosmic rays their science fiction processes need, other than destroying Space Nation B's facilities, or conquering Space Nation B.

Objects that produce cosmic rays might be useful, but given that most cosmic rays seem to originate in supernovas, other energies produced by such objects are much easier to be turned into energy, and produced in significantly larger amounts.

Comment: Super Novae aren't something that happen every day, also, are not the sort of thing one wants to happen in one's own stellar neighbourhood, and can't happen to all stars.  If Space Nation B needs that special Super Nova input, and the suitable local stars are  near to Space Nation A, those stars would be a precious resource for B and something A very much wants to keep unexploited

Answer (score 2):

**Deep space solar winds could be captured using a solar sail.**

[image: solar sail]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Solar_radiation_pressure

Solar sails propel their craft using the output from a star or other energetic object.  WIthin a solar system electromagnetic radiation provides more thrust than thrust from cosmic rays aka the "solar wind".  The main solar wind is supposed to peter out at the "heliopause" boundary of the solar system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind#Outer_limits

But I can imagine a circumstance in dark deep space where localized currents of cosmic rays are indeed valuable, and known currents of such can be used to propel a sailship.  These currents might be from objects more distant and more powerful than a star like ours - perhaps a jet from a distant black hole which remains powerful and directional at great distances from its origin.

Just as predictable useful winds were valuable in the age of sail, predictable currents of charged particles could be useful in the age of solar sail.